# Не работает CMMotionActivityManager на iphone 5 ios 10.3.3

Tags: ios, swift

ничего не могу нагуглить на ошибку CoreLocation: Error occurred while trying to retrieve motion state update: CMErrorDomain Code: 104

В добавок к этому на iphone 5 ios 10.3.3 не работает вот этот блок кода:

```
private let motionManager = CMMotionActivityManager()
.
.
.
motionManager.startActivityUpdates(to: .main, withHandler: {[weak self] activity in self?.setActiveMode(activity?.stationary ?? false)})
```

Что-то мне подсказывает, что это связанно с ошибкой в верху.

P.S. на iphone 8 ios 12.0 все работает
P.S. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Уменьшение движения включено?

Comment: А как это реализовать, можете подсказать пожалуйста?

Comment: Это в настройках телефона.

Comment: Можете подсказать где?

Comment: Посмотрел, выключено